# How can I save all the generated images from the following code to a Zip file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, base64, zip

I need to decode the data in the content_arrays list and generate an image , The following code does that

```
    content_arrays = ['ljfdslkfjaslkfjsdlf' , 'sdfasfsdfsdfsafs'] // Contains a list of base64 encoded data
    i=0
    for content in content_arrays:
        img_data = (content_arrays[i])
        with open(filename, "wb") as fh:
            fh.write(base64.b64decode(img_data))
        i=i+1
```

How can I store all the generated images directly to a single zip file which contains all the images that are generated by decoding the base64 string from the above list[content_arrays].

Current File Structure of the downloaded data ::

```
 -- Desktop 
     -- image1.png
     -- image2.png
```

Required File Structure of the downloaded data ::

```
 -- Desktop
     -- Data.zip 
        -- image1.png
        -- image2.png
```

I've used python zipfile module , but couldn't figure out things.
If there is any possible way , please do give your suggestions ..

Comment: have you looked at the python `zipfile` module?

Comment: Yes @ChrisDoyle , but I couldn't figure out how to use for this scenario

Answer (score 1):

you can just use the zipfile module and then write the content to separate files in the zip. In this example i am just writing the content to a file inside the zip for each item in contents list. I am also using the writestr method  here so i dont have to have physical files on the disk i can just create my content in memory and write it in my zip rather then having to first create it as a file on the OS and then write the file in the zip

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile("data.zip", "w") as my_zip:
    content_arrays = ['ljfdslkfjaslkfjsdlf', 'sdfasfsdfsdfsafs']
    for index, content in enumerate(content_arrays):
        #do what ever you need to do here with your content
        my_zip.writestr(f'file_{index}.txt', content)
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

[image]

Comment: GodSpeed. Thanks Chris

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can iterate over the list of filenames

```
with ZipFile('images.zip', 'w') as zip_obj:
   # Add multiple files to the zip
   for filename in filenames:
       zip_obj.write(filename)
```